# Apache UIMA Ruta Workbench with custom ruta-core

Tags: ruta

In our corpus we often find and need to parse data that is alpha-numeric as a single token (for example file hashes, email addresses, etc.) We have created our own ruta-core version by re-working the JFlex definition. Is there a way we can still work with this new version of ruta-core in Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

If you use simple Ruta projects, you would need to replace the ruta.engine plugin with a different jar containing your ruta-core version. The clean way would be to build a complete update site with your version.

You could maybe also set your ruta-core jar in the classpath of your ruta launch configurations.

If you use maven-based projects, you can set the dependency to your version of ruta-core, which should then be used in the launch delegate.

For your use case, I would not use your own version of ruta-core at all. You could simply write your own version of the TokenLexer, as you probably did. Then, you can configure the utilized TokenLexer in the RutaEngine as there is a configuration parameter for setting it. Thus, there is already some functionality to customize the JFlex definition without building your own ruta-core.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*